# error : pyi_rth_qt4plugins returned -1

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyinstaller

I am creating executable using pyinstaller. (I have installed pyinstaller and pypiwin32 using pip.)

But when I try to run executable created using pyinstaller, it gives me following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 43, in <module>
  File "c:\python27\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py",
 line 517, in load_module
    module = imp.load_module(fullname, fp, filename, ext_tuple)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The application has failed to start because its side-by-side configuration is incorrect.
Please see the application event log or use the command-line sxstrace.exe tool for more detail.
pyi_rth_qt4plugins returned -1
```

I am using --onefile switch with pyinstaller command. In my source file, my library imports look like below

```
import sys
import os
import ctypes
import time
from win32com import client
from datetime import datetime
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
from Main_GUI import Ui_MainWindow
from About_GUI import Ui_About
```

Main_GUI and About_GUI are converted from .ui files using pyuic4

I hope this information helps. Thanks in advance.